# Covert a sequence of continuous characters into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying days to convert a sequence of characters into array .Lets say my sequence would be like var text="abcde"..without any space in the string.All i Wanna do is i wanna convert text into an array like text=[a,b,c,d,e];
Is there any way to do it using javascript .Please Help me

Answer (score 3):

Use split

```
var array = text.split("");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Esailija...I ve been writing split(" "),but never wrote split("")...LOL

Answer (score 2):

Use `split()`:

```
var text = 'abcde',
    textArray = text.split(''); // ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BWGT5/1/).

References:

- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).